# How to provide new class instance within constructor in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `Spring` managed class that extends a base service. I'd like to write the base service in a way that any implementation classes must provide a specific `FileAnalyzer` instance. But I don't want to make the `FileAnalyzer` class to be spring managed.

It that possible? Because a `super()` class always has to be the first call in a constructor, so I cannot instantiate any classes before invoking the base constructor.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseService {
    BaseService(FileAnalyzer analyzer, String path) {
        this.path = path;
        //perform any action with analyzer.
    }
}


@Service
public class TextfileService {
    public TextfileService() {
        //ERROR: super() must be first call in constructor
        FileAnalyzer analyzer = new FileAnalyzer();
        analyzer.configure(..);
        super(analyzer, "c:\logs");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `FileAnalyzer` a custom class written by you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It that possible? Because a super() class always has to be the first call in a constructor

Yes it's possible. Just move the code in a `private static` method and call it from inside the `super()` call.

```
@Service
public class TextfileService {
    public TextfileService() {
        super(getFileAnalyzer(), "c:\logs");
    }
}

private static FileAnalyzer getFileAnalyzer(){
    FileAnalyzer analyzer = new FileAnalyzer();
    analyzer.configure(..);
    return analyzer;
}
```

---

#### Alternative way:

If `FileAnalyzer` is your custom class written by you then just make a change in the return type of the method `configure()` as shown below:

```
@Service
public class TextfileService {
    public TextfileService() {
        super(new FileAnalyzer().configure(...), "c:\logs");
    }
}
```

FileAnalyzer.java

```
public FileAnalyzer configure(){
    ...
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You cannot invoke instance methods before base constructors.

Comment: @kan I missed that part. When I tried it at my system. I used `static` but forget to post it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookup method injection.
Just assign a lookup method and it will be called whenever you instantiate a new object of this class.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483962/579580) answer.